# Find values in between two characters '(' and ')' in column that have nulls

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table name authors. I need to extract the values at the end of their names excluding '(' and ')'.

[image]

I have tried to use a substring with Charindex function.

```
select 
isnull (SUBSTRING(name,CHARINDEX('(',name) +1 ,CHARINDEX(')',name) - CHARINDEX('(',name) - 1), '') as  [Name]
from Authors
```

But I got an error message.

> Msg 537, Level 16, State 3, Line 6
>
> Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

Here is what I am expecting my results to be.

[image]

Comment: [I can't reproduce your problem](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3e0df034b93fbbc27445e52685f96bf4), or at least your query seems to be working with the sample data you provided.

Comment: Are the NULL values actual nulls or a string that reads 'Null'

Comment: Considering that it's been spelt `Null` and not `NULL` @JohnCappelletti ,I think you're on to something. If so, I would suggest the OP updates their data using `NULLIF(Authors,'Null')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare @string nvarchar(25)
```

set @string = '(asdfgh)'

select  REPLACE( REPLACE(@string,'(',''),')','') where @string like '%[(]%%[)]%'

in above code i used regex to find string between ( and ) then replace them by empty

Answer (score 2):

For your data, I would do something like this:

```
select coalesce(replace(stuff(name, 1, charindex('(', name + '(') + 1, ''), ')', ''),
                '') as  [Name]
```

This assumes that the parentheses are at the end of the string, as in the examples.

Answer (score 1):

here you go, apply to your situation

```
declare @string varchar(25)
set @string = '(asdfgh)'
SELECT SUBSTRING(@string, 
    charindex('(', @string)+1, 
    charindex(')', @string)-
    charindex('(', @string)-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `APPLY` :

```
select substring(name, tt.startp + 1, (endp - startp) - 1) as Name
from Authors a cross apply
     ( values (charindex('(', name + ')'), charindex(')', name + ')')) 
     ) tt(startp, endp);
```

Your `Name` column doesn't have a `(`...`)` in some places so, you can add either `where` clause or add explicitly `(`...`)` at the end of string.